# MongoDB Describe Collection

Tags: mongodb

I have a user collection  ,I want to see schema for this collection with data type and other detail,which I want to use in mongoosJs while making Schema.

I found a way on internet ,but it is not providing me full detail of collections-below is code for same

```
var users= db.users.findOne();
```

> for (var key in users) { print (key) ; }

Is there any way to find it.

Comment: What output are you missing exactly when you run this snippet? By the way: You can not "see the schema of a collection" in MongoDB because MongoDB knows no such concept as a schema. Every document in the collection can have any combination of fields, and those fields can have values of any type.

Comment: try this : db.users.find().forEach(printjson). This will print all documents in collection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I discover a mongo database's structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14713179/how-can-i-discover-a-mongo-databases-structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can modify your code as per lines below:-**

```
var col_list = db.users.findOne();
for (var col in col_list) {print (typeof col) }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a schema in mongo. Documents can differ greatly from each other.

So there can be one document where field `username` is String and another document where field `username` is Integer.

You could extract the 'schema' from collection by iterating over all documents and collecting schematic information from all of them and then merging that information. But as far as I know there is no direct way in mongo itself.

Edit: a little googling landed me at [variety.js](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/21923016898/meet-variety-a-schema-analyzer-for-mongodb), which seems to do what you need.