# How to retrieve MongoDb collection validator rules?

Tags: mongodb

On MongoDB 3.4.4 I've created a collection with a validator, but now some inserts fail this rules and I can't understand why.

1. Is there a way to output the rules of the validor? I'm afraid the rules applied are different from what I think they are...
2. Is there a way to improve the error message? "Document failed validation" in this scenario is quite useless.

Thank you!

Comment: using pymongo: `db.get_collection('test').options().get('validator')`

Answer (score 31, accepted):

1. You can see the validation rules (among other collection information) with `db.getCollectionInfos()` for all collections or `db.getCollectionInfos({name: "myCollection"})` for a specific collection: [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.getCollectionInfos/)
2. Have a look at [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/147550/how-do-i-determine-why-a-mongodb-document-is-failing-validation).

Comment: You can also view validation rules in the MongoDB Compass GUI

Answer (score 0):

For Node.js mongodb client, one has to call `db.getCollections`.