# Morphia to return List of strings which are the fields of all documents

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia

If I got a collection full of following elements

```
@Entity
public void MyEntity{
  public String name;
  public String type;
  ...
}
```

And I want to return a `List<String>` (or `Set`) of not the elements, but only their `name` fields.

```
List<String> allNames = datasotre.find(MyEntity.class).asList("name");
```

This is sample query, there is no such method of Morphia datastore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To limit the fields returned call the "retrievedFields" method on Query.  For example, to only get the name field of all MyEntity objects:

```
datastore.find(MyEntity.class).retrievedFields( true, "name").asList()
```

Edit - You can get a list Strings using the following query as long as you don't mind that the list will only contain unique values (i.e. no duplicate names):

```
DBCollection m = datastore.getCollection( MyEntity.class );
List names = m.distinct( "name", new BasicDBObject() );
```

The "names" list will only contain Strings.

Comment: I wanted something that returns a List<String>, not List<MyEntity>.

Comment: There is no feature in morphia like this nor can I see why it would be added. If you want a distinct list of all values in the name fields then you can use the driver directly as is suggested above.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that there is no actual query for "keys". The queries all return "key/value pairs".

In theory, the fields in `datastore.find()` should map to the fields in `MyEntity` so you *could* just use reflection. However, if you have other people writing to the DB from different places they may have seeded extra tables.

If this is the case, you will need to run a Map/Reduce to get the list of all the "key" names.

There is [a sample here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997004/).

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `datastore.find(MyEntity.class).retrievedFields(true, "name").asList();`. This will contain the _id and name attribute.

See http://code.google.com/p/morphia/wiki/Query#Ignoring_Fields

Comment: I wanted something that returns a List<String>, not List<MyEntity>.