# Error while doing a map-reduce using pymongo

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, pymongo

> pymongo.errors.OperationFailure: db assertion failure, assertion: 'can't create index on system.indexes', assertionCode: 13143

I am seeing this error when I am trying to use map-reduce to retrieve all the keys from the documents.
The code i am using is one similar to:
[mapreduceforgettingkeys(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997004/using-map-reduce-for-mapping-the-properties-in-a-collection)
An interesting thing to note is that I am not seeing the same error on another server when I run  the same code.

The only difference between these 2 servers is one is dormant(no new data is being copied) and on another one huge amount of data is being dumped.

Comment: I assume the server you are dumping is the one returning the error? Are you using mongodump? If so, what options? Did you fsync/lock the database before dumping it?

Comment: I am using the db.insert/db.update to dump(insert) documents, but these operations are via REST calls.
yes , you are right error is being seen in the active server!

Comment: Is there anyone who knows wat this error might mean , I tried looking @ the code.But was not able to figure out much :(

Comment: Can you provide any systems information?  What version of mongodb and pymongo?  Are the configs of the servers are the same? Its just one of them is underload?