# How to get all the keys of a Json document using pymongo?

Tags: python, json, pymongo

I have a document in the below format,

```
   {
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

I need to get all the keys including nested keys. But I can able to get only the keys in the first level, eg: glossary.

Can someone tell me, is there any way to retrive all the keys?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997004/using-map-reduce-for-mapping-the-properties-in-a-collection).

Comment: I don't want to retrieve documents from collection, This is done before inserting document into MongoDB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function to dig through every layer and print the key.

```
def recurse_keys(document):
    for key in document.keys():
        print(str(key))
        if isinstance(document[key], dict):
           recurse_keys(document[key])
```

**UPDATE:**
 For Nested Format

```
def recurse_keys(document,parent):
    for key in document.keys():
        if parent!="":
            print(parent+'.'+str(key))
        else:
            print str(key)
        if isinstance(document[key], dict):
            if parent!="":
                recurse_keys(document[key],parent+'.'+str(key))
            else:
                recurse_keys(document[key],str(key))
```

Comment: This works fine, Thanks much !!  but is there any way to get key as a nested format?

Comment: Ya ,you can just send the parent key as another argument and append it before printing the key. I will update my answer to reflect it.

Answer (score 1):

```
from re import findall
input_dict = {
"glossary": {
    "title": "example glossary",
    "GlossDiv": {
        "title": "S",
        "GlossList": {
            "GlossEntry": {
                "ID": "SGML",
                "SortAs": "SGML",
                "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                "Acronym": "SGML",
                "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                "GlossDef": {
                    "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                    "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                },
                "GlossSee": "markup"
            }
        }
    }
}
}
dict1=str(input_dict)
pattern = r"'([A-Za-z0-9_\./\\-]*)':"
m = findall(pattern, dict1)
print m
```

m is :-
['glossary', 'GlossDiv', 'GlossList', 'GlossEntry', 'GlossDef', 'GlossSeeAlso', 'para', 'GlossSee', 'Acronym', 'GlossTerm', 'Abbrev', 'SortAs', 'ID', 'title', 'title']

Let me tell you this **works fine if you simply want to have all keys** but if you want them to be in nested form then **better go the recursion way**.Will provide the recursion code once it is done.

Please suggest me if some improvements are possible in my current solution.

Comment: You are right. I need the keys in a nested format :-(