# How to get all the keys from MongoDB document using some dynamic function?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb, as per requirement I need to get all the keys from
below MongoDB document or any other documents, using some dynamic function.

MongoDB example document:

```
{
      "encryption": {
        "alg":"AES",
        "encryption_key":"lkjhsdflkhsdfwe22348423"
      },
      "domain": "PBTV",
          "detokenObject": [{ 
            "client": {
              "FORENAMES":"^^^ABCDEFG",
              "SURNAME":"^^^ABCDFHE",
              "COUNTRY":"England",          
            "transactions": [ 
              {  
                "TYPE":"buy",
              },
              {  
                "TYPE":"sell",
                "AMT":"1000"
              },{
                "AMT":"1000000000000000001"
              }
            ]
          } ,
            "client1": {
              "SURNAME":"^^^ABCDFHE",
              "COUNTRY":"England",          
            "transactions": [ 
              {  
                "TYPE":"buy",
                "ASSET":"NYSE:APPL",
                "AMT":"100"
              },
              {  
                "TYPE":"sell",
                "ASSET":"NYSE:APPL",
                "AMT":"1000"
              }
            ]     
        }
        }]
    }
```

Please provide any solution?

Comment: Please provide me with beer for the rest of my life. What have you tried so far? And, as a side node: there is a [16MB size limit on BSON documents](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#BSON-Document-Size). One of my mantras: [Overembedding is the root of all evil.](http://blog.mahlberg.io/blog/2015/11/05/data-modelling-for-mongodb/).

Comment: What do you expect in the result?

Comment: @Markus W Mahlberg :Thanks for your response, so far i have not done much but wrote this function to iterate detokenObject array.                     db.detoken_vault.aggregate(
    { $project: { detokenObject: 1 }},
    { $unwind: "$detokenObject" },
    { $group: { _id: "result", count: { $sum: 1 }}}
);

Comment: @AlexBlex : requirement is to write a dynamic function to get all the keys from BSON object and store somewhere in list.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997004/using-map-reduce-for-mapping-the-properties-in-a-collection

Comment: It would be nice to see what you expect in the result for the given example. "all keys in a list" is quite ambiguous.