# How to get all attributes of collection in mongo through Java Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

My requirement is that I have to write a service in Spring to fetch all attributes of a collection in Mongo.
The solutions that I've found explain how to get attributes using mongo shell.

[Using map/reduce for mapping the properties in a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997004/using-map-reduce-for-mapping-the-properties-in-a-collection)

Now I want to do the same thing in programmatic way in Java, How should I do it?

Comment: The representation of JavaScript functions with the Java driver is really just "strings". You really should not do or even "need" this sort of thing in a production environment anyway. So I would strongly suggest you don't.