# Return actual type of a field in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

In MongoDB, using `$type`, it is possible to filter a search based on if the field matches a BSON data type (see [DOCS](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-ConditionalOperator%3A%7B%7B%24type%7D%7D)).

For eg.

```
db.posts.find({date2: {$type: 9}}, {date2: 1})
```

which returns:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4c0ec11e8fd2e65c0b010000"), 
    "date2" : "Fri Jul 09 2010 08:25:26 GMT" 
}
```

I need a query that will tell me what the actual type of the field is, for every field in a collection. Is this possible with MongoDB?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

OK, here are some related questions that may help:

[Get all field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/) in a collection using map-reduce.

Here's [a recursive version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/) that lists all possible fields.

Hopefully that can get you started. However, I suspect that you're going to run into some issues with this request. There are two problems here:

1. I can't find a "gettype" function for JSON. You can query by `$type`, but it doesn't look like you can actually run a `gettype` function on a field and have that maps back to the BSON type.
2. A field can contain data of multiple types, so you'll need a plan to handle this. Even if it's not apparent Mongo could store some numbers as ints and others floats without you really knowing. In fact, with the PHP driver, this is quite possible.

So if you assume that you can solve problem #1, then you should be able to solve problem #2 using a slight variation on *"Get all field Names"*.

It would probably look something like this:

```
"map" : function() { for (var key in this) { emit(key, [ typeof value[key] ]); } }
"reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return (key, add_to_set(stuff) ); }
```

So basically you would emit the `key` and the `type of key value` (as an array) in the map function. Then from the reduce function you would add unique entries for each type.

At the end of the run you would have data like this

`{"_id":[255], "name" : [1,5,8], ... }`

Of course, this is all a lot of work, depending on your actual problem, you may just want to ensure (from your code) that you're always putting in the right type of data. Finding the type of data after the data is in the DB is definitely a pain.

Answer (score 42):

Starting from MongoDB 3.4, you can use the [`$type`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/type/) aggregation operator to return a field's type.

```
db.posts.aggregate( 
    [ 
        { "$project": { "fieldType": {  "$type": "$date2"  } } } 
    ]
)
```

which yields:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("4c0ec11e8fd2e65c0b010000"), 
    "fieldType" : "string" 
}
```

Comment: This example from the mongodb docs is a bit clearer (basically turning "$date2" above into "$fieldType"), such as here: db.coll.aggregate([{
    $project: {
       a : { $type: "$a" }
    }
}])

Answer (score 30):

type the below query in mongo shell

```
  typeof db.employee.findOne().first_name
```

Syntax

```
 typeof db.collection_name.findOne().field_name
```

Comment: This will give the JS type, which may differ from the BSON type. For example, if you do typeof db.employee.findOne()._id, you will get "string," but the BSON type is "Object id."

Answer (score 4):

Taking advantage of the styvane query, I added a $group listing to make it easier to read when we have different data types.

```
db.posts.aggregate( 
[ 
    { "$project": { _id:0, "fieldType": {  "$type": "$date2"  } } },
    {"$group": { _id: {"fieldType": "$fieldType"},count: {$sum: 1}}}
])
```

And have this result:

```
{ "_id" : { "fieldType" : "missing" }, "count" : 50 }
{ "_id" : { "fieldType" : "date" }, "count" : 70 }
{ "_id" : { "fieldType" : "string" }, "count" : 10 }
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Noting that `a=5;a.constructor.toString()` prints `function Number() { [native code] }`, one can do something similar to:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
function() {
    emit(this._id.constructor.toString()
       .replace(/^function (\S+).+$/,  "$1"), 1);
}, 
function(k, v) {
    return Array.sum(v);
}, 
{ 
    out: { inline: 1 } 
});
```