# With mongodb, how can I query for all document property names and types within a collection?

Tags: mongodb

I have recently started using MongoDB for the first time. I need to store data who’s schema I don’t necessarily know up front. MongoDB obviously looks like a great fit for this, being a schema-less database.

However I am currently struggling on the querying side as to how I can help users form queries without knowing upfront what fields exist for them query against.

An example, imagine I have the following collection:

```
[
    {
        _id: ObjectId("576b3bc324234cdf7ddsb098"),
        timeStamp: ISODate("2015-08-24T09:03:27.887+0000"),
        action: "login",
        performedBy: {
            username: "Annonymous User",
            ip: "192.168.0.5"
        },
        performedOn: {
            type: "User",
            username: "Stan.Marsh",
            ip: "192.168.0.5"
        },
        outcome: "Success"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("576bbc6c43385c2d84b7b098"),
        timeStamp: ISODate("2015-08-24T09:04:27.887+0000"),
        action: "update",
        performedBy: {
            username: "Stan.Marsh",
            firstName: "Stan",
            lastName: "Marsh",
            ip: "192.168.0.5"
        },
        performedOn: {
            Before: {
                type: "Product",
                Name: "Cheesy Poofs",
                weight: "30g"
            },
            After: {
                type: "Product",
                Name: "Cheesy Poofs Extreme",
                weight: "35g"
            }            
        },
        outcome: "Success"
    },
    {
        _id: ObjectId("576b3bc32423dfgdfg45f"),
        timeStamp: ISODate("2015-08-24T09:05:27.887+0000"),
        action: "logout",
        performedBy: {
            username: "Stan.Marsh",
            firstName: "Stan",
            lastName: "Marsh",
            ip: "192.168.0.5"
        },
        outcome: "Success"
    }
]
```

The actual structure of the data above is not important to me so feel free to suggest something you feel would work better, but my aim is to try and keep it as simple as possible.

Now for me to provide a usable query builder UI, I need to be able to find out from this data what fields exist, and what type of data it is (so I can provide relevant UI operations such as if its a date, offer a date range for example).

Therefore query the above collection for something like... (again specific structure not important, just content)

```
[
    { name: "timeStamp", type: "Date" },
    { name: "action", type: "String" },
    { name: "performedBy", type: "Object", fields: [
            { name: "username", type: "String" },
            { name: "ip", type: "String" },
            { name: "firstName", type: "String" },
            { name: "lastname", type: "String" }
        ]
    },
    { name: "performedOn", type: "Object", fields: [
            { name: "type", type: "String" },
            { name: "username", type: "String" },
            { name: "ip", type: "String" },
            { name: "before", type: "Object", fields: [
                  { name: "type", type: "String" },
                  { name: "name", type: "String" },
                  { name: "weight", type: "String" }
                ]
            },
            { name: "after", type: "Object", fields: [
                    { name: "type", type: "String" },
                    { name: "name", type: "String" },
                    { name: "weight", type: "String" }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The above represents a flattened hierarchy of all the fields defined that could be used to form the sort of interface I am after. Just to note I do see the issue with the possibility of multiple fields with the same name existing with different types, but for example purposes, I hope the above effectively communicates what I am trying to achieve.

Also just to note, in the contrived example above it would be easy to solve this outside of mongo by defining types for each of the above collection objects which I can then reflect over, but one important aspect of this is that it is version agnostic, and therefore allows users to query on the data they have, no matter how its schema has evolved over time, which is why this approach, if possible, is better.

Thank you in advance :)

Ste.

Comment: As a final note, I have considered representing the data as a tree structure which makes querying for the fields easier, but on the the flip side makes the actual user query translation more complicated (in my basic experience). So only want to explore that if a simpler solution does not exist on a more natural data structure as illustrated.

Comment: Also I believe this should be possible with map reduce, but as I understand it is about 70% less performant than find & aggregation framework (read that in a white paper) and therefore not intended for realtime results. I ideally need a realtime or near realtime (then backed with caching) solution for this to be viable. :S I am obviously willing to relax my very strict constraints if I have too, I just don't want to start there!

Comment: have you checked loose schemas ?

Comment: [You just broke the rule](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5NylmdC_uEM) by asking two questions in one post. That being said, your questions  are respectively the duplicate of [MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection) and [Return actual type of a field in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208538/return-actual-type-of-a-field-in-mongodb)