# How to get field data type from MongoDB using java

Tags: java, mongodb

This is my code:

```
List<Document> documents = (List<Document>) collection.find().into(new 
ArrayList<Document>());
for (Document document : documents) {
    Set s = document.keySet();
    Iterator iter = s.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        set.add(iter.next());
    }
}
```

I am able to get collection keys.But how to get datatype of those keys from mongodb using java. Could you please help on this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208538/return-actual-type-of-a-field-in-mongodb

Comment: Whats your document type equivalent in java?

Comment: i have different datatypes in my Collection like String , int and in java equivalent data types are String, double,int . By using below code i am getting collection.         MongoDatabase md =  m.getDatabase(db);
    MongoCollection<Document> collection = md
      .getCollection(tableName);

Comment: You  can try `List<Class> class = document.values().stream().map(Object::getClass).collect(Collectors.toList());`