# How do I select all fields/columns from a collection using monary?

Tags: mongodb, monary

I am using [Monary](https://monary.readthedocs.io)

I have a database in Mongo with a lot of rows and columns. Currently, the way I am using monary is as follows:

```
client = Monary()
data = client.query("static_database",             # Database name
                     "properties",                 # Collection name 
                      {},                          # Query
                     ["Name","Address1","Address2"], # Field/col names
                     ["string:72"]*3)              # The types of each 
                                                   # field/col
```

The collection `properties` has a lot of field names and I want to take most if not all of those fields into `data`. Typing more than 10 fields into a list seems like a pain.

I also want to use different collections in the future, so a way of getting all column/field names would help a lot. I read through the docs and [FAQs](https://monary.readthedocs.io/faq.html), yet haven't been able to find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using pyMongo to get all respective column names, using the code provided by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/get-names-of-all-keys-in-the-collection) and mapReduce [documentation](https://api.mongodb.com/python/2.0/examples/map_reduce.html).

The next problem was `type`. It was pretty annoying to try and find the type of each field (each field could have items of multiple types). I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208538/return-actual-type-of-a-field-in-mongodb). But it seemed like a mess, so I ended up just taking a [random entry from mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2824157/random-record-from-mongodb) that hopefully contained all the fields.

There should be a better way of getting type names, but I did not implement that. The final messy and bad implementation is as follows:

```
def getColsfromdb(supplier_name):
    client = MongoClient()
    db = client['supplier_static_database']
    map = Code("function(){   for (var key in this) {emit(key,null);} }") 
    reduce = Code("function(key, stuff) {return null;}")
    pT = getattr(db, supplier_name)
    mR = pT.map_reduce(map,reduce,supplier_name + "_keys")

    types_ = [type(v).__name__ for k,v in sorted(pT.find().limit(-1).skip(100).next().items())]

    cols4db = []
    for doc in mR.find():
        cols4db.append(doc["_id"])
    cols4db = sorted(cols4db)

    for i,t in enumerate(types_):
        if "unicode" in t:
            types_[i] = "string:50"
        if "ObjectId" in t:
            types_[i] = "id"
        if "list" in t or "NoneType" in t:
            types_[i] = "string:50"
        if "int" in t:
            types_[i]="int64"
        if "float" in t:
            types_[i]="float64"

    try:
        assert len(types_)==len(cols4db)
    except:
        tmpdiff = len(types_)-len(cols4db)
        if tmpdiff<0:
            for i in range(abs(tmpdiff)):
                types_.append("string:10")
        else:
            del cols4db[-tmpdiff:]

    return cols4db,types_
```

Initially, I had the `except` generate a random number every time it failed, but decided to stick with "randomly chosen" 100.