# MongoDB query for distinct $type of a given field

Tags: mongodb

With MongoDB's flexible schema, I'd like to learn the varying "$type" for a given field.

For example I can query to see all documents that meet the type I expect by

`db.getCollection('sample').find({"_id": {$type: 7}})`

How can I get a list of `$type` for `sample._id` ?

Or how can I re-write this query to show all documents that do not match the given type number?

Thanks!

Comment: Another approach to consider would  be using a tool/library that does type detection, for example [`mongodb-schema`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongodb-schema).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find all of the type for a given field, you'll want to use a mongo aggregation pipeline: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/

If you want to rewrite this query to find all of the documents that are *not* of a certain type, you can use the $not operator -- https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/

`{"_id": { $not: { $type: 7}}}`

Not related to your question, but mongo 3.6 added aliases for types, so you could also write that query as `{"_id": { $not: { $type: "objectId"}}}` https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/type/

Answer (score 2):

I was interested to get distinct value types of the certain field in the collection and the following request helps me

```
db.getCollection('<collection_name>').aggregate([
   { $project: { "fieldType": {  "$type": "$<field_name>"  } } } 
  ,{ $group : {_id: "$fieldType"} }
])
```

used links:
[Return actual type of a field in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208538/return-actual-type-of-a-field-in-mongodb)

Comment: It's looking exactly like what I want but I'm getting `invalid operator '$type'`, even though filtering by $type works in a `find` query

Comment: seems like a db version related issue