# How to show all columns in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I was wondering how you would find all of the column names in a table in MongoDB, like how you use `SHOW COLUMNS FROM foo;` in mysql.

Comment: Looks like there is a better answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection

Answer (score 22, accepted):

MongoDB is schemaless and does not have tables. In MongoDB, each collection can have different types of items. You could store two very different items in the same collection:

```
db.test.insert( { "SomeString" : "How much wood would the woodchop chop ..." } );
db.test.insert( { "Amount": 2040.20, "Due": new ISODate("2012-11-10"), "UserId" : new ObjectId("...")} );
```

usually the objects are somehow related or have a common base type, but it's not required.

You can, however, take a look at invidual records using

```
db.collectionName.findOne()
```

or

```
db.collectionName.find().pretty()
```

However, there's no guarantee from MongoDB that any two records look alike or have the same fields: **there's no schema**.