# How to get all keys + in a collection + mongodb +mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to get all distinct keys from a collections in mongoDB.
I refereed the following links:

[Get names of all keys in the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/get-names-of-all-keys-in-the-collection)

[Querying for a list of all distinct fields in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11118039/querying-for-a-list-of-all-distinct-fields-in-mongodb-collection) and etc.

But still i didn't get the right solution...

As i am using mongoose in the first link reference syas runCommand is not a function.

As `findOne()` will give the first document keys alone but i need all distnct keys

```
userModel.findOne(condition, projection, callback)
```

Please share your ideas..

Comment: Keys means your declared `Model` in mongoose ? I mean let's say you have a model named Book which is `{_id,book_name,publisher}` etc, Do you want them?

Comment: @Osman Goni Nahid yes u r right

Comment: check my answer.

Comment: @Anthony Winzlet  Its not a particular filed. I have to get the all the keys in all documents..

Comment: Try the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570730/2683814

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mongoose 3.x, then you can try this :

```
userModel.find().distinct('_id', function(error, ids) {
    // ids is an array of all ObjectIds
});
```

Or you can find all the documents and extract key from that like :

```
var keys = {};
var docKeys = [];
userModel.find({}, function(err, allDocs){
    allDocs.forEach(function(doc){
        docKeys = Object.keys(doc);
        docKeys.forEach(function(docKey){
               if(!keys[docKey]) keys[docKey] = true;
        })
    })     
})
```

I have just written for getting logic, you can change according to your requirements and efficiency

Comment: Its giving array of  `_ids` but i need `keys`

Comment: I have updated the code, please check if it solves your problem.

Comment: i already implemented your 2 thought. But what about performance?? Consider if it has some 1 lakh resords??

Comment: you can use schema and put restriction on document keys. so you will be sure that document will contain only those keys, and you can get the schema keys using : UserModel.schema.paths

Comment: Thats i cant restrict.. User can upload any datas

Answer (score 0):

Try like this you will get all of your keys defined into your mongoose model/Schema.

```
import Model from 'your_model_path'

for(let property in Model.schema.obj){
  console.log("key=====>",property);
}
```

Comment: My schema is not fixed, user can upload any data, so ew cant predict the keys

Comment: then you have to do lengthy things the different doc can be different, merging docs and finding keys too costly.

Comment: .Yes Any optimized solutioon for this??