# Retrieving distinct properties

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I want to allow storing documents with a standard set of properties, but also have the ability to add any number of custom properties.  Given a filter, I would like to quickly (i.e. not having to iterate through each doc) get a unique/distinct list of those custom properties.  Is there a standard/recommended way of getting them or do I have to essentially manually index myself when storing a document?

Comment: @StanleyGong - I don't believe `DISTINCT` will help the OP, as that returns distinct *values* for a property. If I'm reading the question correct, the OP wants distinct *property names*.

Comment: There is no way to get a list of properties in use; you would have to discover (or track) this yourself.

Comment: @ImrePühvel: Your link was useful.  Also, this MongoDB answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11119091/177333) had an interesting implementation idea: with each document store the field names as values so that you can query them.  I'll have to think of the best approach and maybe do some testing, but this gives me a good starting point.

Comment: @DavidMakogon: You're correct, I was looking for property names, not the values. 
 Thanks for the confirmation that it's not possible.