# Unwind object in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection like this

```
[{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590c2331dc1a05e7d3525e70"),
    "name" : "Orange",
    "quarters" : {
        "first" : 20,
        "middle" : 53,
        "last" : 52
    }
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("590c2405dc1a05e7d3525e71"),
    "name" : "Apple",
    "quarters" : {
        "first" : 42,
        "middle" : 37,
        "last" : 16
    }
}]
```

and I want result like this

```
[{
    name: "Orange",
    first: 20
},{
    name: "Orange",
    middle: 53
},{
    name: "Orange",
    last: 52
},{
    name: "Apple",
    first: 42
},{
    name: "Apple",
    middle: 37
},{
    name: "Apple",
    last: 16
}]
```

I tried to find the solution and I found few question similar to this question but no luck

- [$unwind an object in aggregation framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189243/unwind-an-object-in-aggregation-framework)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try below aggregation pipeline in `3.4.4` version.

Change the `quarters` embedded document into array of key value pairs using `$objectToArray`  followed by `$unwind` and `$zip` each `quarters` key value pair  separately followed by `$arrayToObject` to create original structure.

Use `$addFields` to push the `name` field into `quarters`.

Use `$replaceRoot` to promote the `quarters` embedded document to top level.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{$addFields: {quarters: {$objectToArray: "$quarters"}}}, 
{$unwind:"$quarters"},
{$addFields:{quarters: {"$arrayToObject":{$zip:{inputs:[["$quarters.k"], ["$quarters.v"]]}}}}},
{$addFields:{"quarters.name": "$name"}},
{$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$quarters"}}
])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but still could it be done using MongoDB 3.2 ?

Comment: You are welcome. I'm afraid it may not be possible with the current schema in 3.2. Is updating your schema an option for you ?

Answer (score 1):

You can get it like this:

```
var inputCollection = [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("590c2331dc1a05e7d3525e70"),
    "name" : "Orange",
    "quarters" : {
        "first" : 20,
        "middle" : 53,
        "last" : 52
    }
}, {
    "_id" : ObjectId("590c2405dc1a05e7d3525e71"),
    "name" : "Apple",
    "quarters" : {
        "first" : 42,
        "middle" : 37,
        "last" : 16
    }
}];

var output = [];

inputCollection.forEach(function(obj){
    for (var key in obj.quarters) {
      if (obj.quarters.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
         output.push({ name:obj.name, key: obj.quarters[key] });
      }
    }
});

console.log("The output is :", output); // It will print your desired output.
```

I hope this will help.

Thanks.