# Get object at the root level mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

document:

```
{"_id":"5cb0dfe234a8a30c9c0af127",
"sensors":
[{"value0":0.153,
"value1":-0.306,
"value2":9.807}],
"timestamp":1555095522489,"__v":0}
```

I want to get 4 field (timestamp and value 0..2) without any array / object.
unwind work only against array but not objects. What should I do?

desired output :

```
{timestamp":1555095522489,
value0":0.153,
value1":-0.306,
value2":9.807}
```

Comment: What should be the output?

Comment: all documents from collection in format : timestamp, value0, value1, value2 
{1555095522489, 0.153, -0.306, 9.807}

Comment: Please show the output in JSON format by editing your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11189243/unwind-an-object-in-aggregation-framework

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [**`$replaceRoot`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/) aggregation operators

```
db.collection.aggregate([   
  { "$unwind": "$sensors" },
  { "$replaceRoot": { "newRoot": { "$mergeObjects": ["$sensors", { "timestamp": "$timestamp" }] }}} 
])
```