# MongoDB Query to find out all the array elements of a collection

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb, nosql

I have a pretty big MongoDB document that holds all kinds of data. I need to identify the fields that are of type array in a collection so I can remove them from the displayed fields in the grid that I will populate.

My method now consists of retrieving all the field names in the collection with

*This was taken from the response posted here [MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection)*

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "Product",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "things" + "_keys"
})

db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
```

And running for each of the fields a query like this one

```
db.Product.find( { $where : "Array.isArray(this.Orders)" } ).count()
```

If there's anything retrieved the field is considered an array.

I don't like that I need to run n+2 queries ( n being the number of different fields in my collection ) and I wouldn't like to hardcode the fields in the model. It would defeat the whole purpose of using MongoDB.

Is there a better method of doing this ?

Answer (score 0):

I made a couple of slight modifications to the code you provided above:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "Product",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { 
       if (Array.isArray(this[key])) {
          emit(key, 1); 
       } else {
          emit(key, 0);
       }
    }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return Array.sum(stuff); }, 
  "out": "Product" + "_keys"
})
```

Now, the mapper will emit a 1 for keys that contain arrays, and a 0 for any that do not.  The reducer will sum these up, so that when you check your end result:

```
db[mr.result].find()
```

You will see your field names with the number of documents in which they contain Array values (and a 0 for any that are never arrays).

So this should give you which fields contain Array types with just the map-reduce job.

--

Just to see it with some data:

```
db.Product.insert({"a":[1,2,3], "c":[1,2]})
db.Product.insert({"a":1, "b":2})
db.Product.insert({"a":1, "c":[2,3]})
```

(now run the "mr =" code above)

```
db[mr.result].find()
{ "_id" : "_id", "value" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "a", "value" : 1 }
{ "_id" : "b", "value" : 0 }
{ "_id" : "c", "value" : 2 }
```