# MongoDB using $returnKey to get Field Name and value

Tags: mongodb

I have run into trouble with MongoDB. I am trying to get value of a field, where field name is not known to me and use the retrieved value to check existence of a different document in collection. I am only aware of pattern of value the field might be containing.

Let me explain, I have following document structure:

```
db.blogs_data.find({"_id.r":"http://blog_post_url/authors"}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : {
        "r" : "http://blog_post_url/authors"
    },
    "author:_1" : {
        "u" : "People:C2CE29E7"
    },    
    "author:_2" : {
        "u" : "Organisations:0B2A962A-8D1C"
    },
    "rdf:type" : {
        "u" : "rdf:Seq"
    }
}
```

Here author:_2 can be anything like : author:_N (numeric). 
Now, details of each sequence in above decument is stored as a separate document, something like :

```
db.blogs_data.find({"_id.r":"People:C2CE29E7"}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : {
        "r" : "People:C2CE29E7"
    },
    "rdf:type" : {
        "u" : "foaf:Person"
    },
    "foaf:name" : {
        "l" : "McCabe, Catherine"
    }
}


db.blogs_data.find({"_id.r":"Organisations:0B2A962A-8D1C"}).pretty();
{
    "_id" : {
        "r" : "Organisations:0B2A962A-8D1C"
    },
    "rdf:type" : {
        "u" : "foaf:Organisations"
    },
    "foaf:name" : {
        "l" : "ABC Publications"
    }
}
```

Now, I need to get value of each sequence of /authors, where author value pattern is like : "Organisations*", and use value from sequence to 
check author details documents, like if it actually exists or not.
I've checked MongoDB, and it does have $returnKey, that it says returns Index key or Keys, 
http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/operator/returnKey/#op._S_returnKey
but, document seems to be incomplete and bit confusing for me too, like : 
" If $returnKey is set to true and the query does not use an index to perform the read operation, the returned documents will not contain any fields."

Well, I don't know exact key where this value is, and just value inside it. I've also checked this [MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection) however, it returns unique keys in a collection.

It seems to me that a Mongo query won't do what I want to do here, and I've to write a JS script to do this. Is there someone facing the same or similar problem? In case of JS, what should be considered as starting point?

Regards,

Comment: Take a look at this idea http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/indexes/#how-can-i-effectively-use-indexes-strategy-for-attribute-lookups and see if you can apply it to your problem.

Comment: well, not sure. most of the solution I've seen works using field name, however, here, I am aware of value inside field, but not field name...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved my problem by :

using a regex to get all mongo documents where *id.r is ends with **/authors**, and looping through each **author***:N inside authors document and use value of **author_:N** to check existence of actual author document.

Ravish