# Count of null and not null by _ID in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Looking to create a report on a set of data which shows how densely / sparesely populated the data set is.

Specificially, i'd like to

1. Iterate through each _ID (there are about 250 within the dataset so manually crafting them would be very time consuming)
2. For each_ID produce a count of NULL / NOT NULL values
3. output the above like so:

CUstomer_ID        350000     0
Customer_Name      150000 200000
Customer_DOB       200000 150000

Any hints / tips on how to do this? I've searched for a while but iterating through all of the _ID keys seems to be possible via mapreduce:

[MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection)

and then used this:

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "mpfs",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "mpfs" + "_keys"
})
```

but then i'm not sure how to use the mapreduce set to feed another query that would produce the results.

I'm also unsure as to whether this is the most efficient way of doing this as i'm from an SQL background...is there a more efficient way?

Comment: You don't provide enough detail for an answer, but you'd typically use an [aggregation pipeline](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline/) to do this.

Comment: Hi JohnnyHK - thanks for the reply. I've got the keys into a result set, but am still unsure of how to use this within an aggregation pipeline - db[mr.result].distinct("_id") contians my result set but I can't seem to figure the syntax to run something like: db.mpfs.aggregate(
 { 
          $group : {_id : db[mr.result].distinct("_id"), total: { $exists: true }}
 }
 );

Comment: We need more detail to help. What do the documents look like? Is the document structure known/specified?

Comment: Hi Wdberkely - the structure isn't known / specified unfortunately, there are a set of .csv files which have some overlap and some differences. My initial results set was collected by: