# MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection using c#

Tags: c#, mongodb

How can I get names of all the keys in a MongoDB collection using c#. 
I am using mongocsharpdriver.
I am able to get all the records using

`var collection1 = database1.GetCollection("Games").FindAll();`

Now I need the key names to display/use it. I need key names of collection that I have fetched.
e.g. If I have collection which

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("c3"), "GameID" : 20, "GameName" : "COD5", "Cost" : 100}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("c4"), "GameID" : 21, "GameName" : "NFS", "Publisher" : "EA"}
{ "_id" : ObjectId("c5"), "GameID" : 22, "GameName" : "CS", "Cost" : 200}
```

So I should get list of keys like GameID, GameName, Cost, Publisher.

I also went through [MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection) but was not able to implement it, didnot understood it & got problem with mapreduce.

Comment: That op is a one-liner for Java, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34022951/get-names-of-all-keys-name-in-collection-using-java/34023145#34023145. Maybe it's translateable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspired from the link in your question:

```
string map = @"function() { 
        for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
        }";
string reduce = @"function(key, stuff) { return null; }";
string finalize = @"function(key, value){
            return key;
        }";
MapReduceArgs args = new MapReduceArgs();
args.FinalizeFunction = new BsonJavaScript(finalize);
args.MapFunction = new BsonJavaScript(map);
args.ReduceFunction = new BsonJavaScript(reduce);
var results = collection1.MapReduce(args);
foreach (BsonValue result in results.GetResults().Select(item => item["_id"]))
{
    Console.WriteLine(result.AsString);
}
```

Comment: I think the OP is looking for the names of the *keys*, not the distinct set of *values*.

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood your question. I update my answer

Answer (score 0):

A very inefficient, but simple way to do this is

```
HashSet<string> keys = new HashSet<string>();
foreach (var rover in collection1.FindAll())
{
    rover.Names.ToList().ForEach(p => keys.Add(p));
}
```

Keep in mind that finding the set of keys, no matter how it's implemented, will always have to **iterate the entire collection**, so it will be terribly slow on larger collections.

It makes sense to use Map/Reduce for this problem on larger collections, because that avoids all the data transfer and deserialization overhead that is incurred by the solution I posted above, but you should generally try to avoid doing something like this *at all*. At least, don't do it where it's needed synchronously.

If you somehow need to know the set of all fields quickly, you're better off keeping track of the fields during *writes* and store the list of fields in a separate collection somewhere.