# Get names of all keys name in collection using Java

Tags: java, mongodb

In this collection (called "play")

```
{ "_id" : 0 , "outlook" : "sunny" , "temp" : "hot" , "humidity" : "high" , "windy" : "weak" , "lable" : "no"}
{ "_id" : 1 , "outlook" : "sunny" , "temp" : "hot" , "humidity" : "high" , "windy" : "strong" , "lable" : "no"}
{ "_id" : 2 , "outlook" : "overcast" , "temp" : "hot" , "humidity" : "high" , "windy" : "weak" , "lable" : "yes"}
{ "_id" : 3 , "outlook" : "rain" , "temp" : "mild" , "humidity" : "high" , "windy" : "weak" , "lable" : "yes"}
{ "_id" : 4 , "outlook" : "rain" , "temp" : "cool" , "humidity" : "normal" , "windy" : "weak" , "lable" : "yes"}
{ "_id" : 5 , "outlook" : "rain" , "temp" : "cool" , "humidity" : "normal" , "windy" : "strong" , "lable" : "no"}
```

How can I retrieve the names of the keys using Java?

Example output:

```
[ "_id" , "outlook" , "temp" , "humidity" , "windy" , "lable" ]
```

The code looks like this so far

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DB dbtest = connection.dbconn();
        DBCollection collection = dbtest.getCollection("play");
        BasicDBObject allQuery = new BasicDBObject();;

        DBCursor cursor = collection.find(allQuery);
        while (cursor.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(cursor.next());
        }

     /**
       write code.. here...
     */   
    }
}
```

Comment: We're not going to write the code for you. You're already off to a good start, why don't you try assigning `cursor.next()` to a variable and see what you can do with that variable.

Comment: i want key names only. no need values

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code-writing service.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli: Maybe he just needs a little pointer to the API.

Comment: @user then it should be rephrased to be on-topic, because what I see right now is only "please write this code for me".

Comment: can you try this code in mongoshell
**doc=db.thinks.findOne();
for (key in doc) print(key);**

Comment: @mohamedzajith: For a mongoshell solution see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection?rq=1

Comment: i know but how to write java code

Comment: @MarcoBonelli Answer is working
I got the Answer which expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look in the API at [`DBCursor.next()`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBCursor.html#next--), it returns a [`DBObject`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/com/mongodb/DBObject.html), which is a subtype of [`BSONObject` with a `keySet()`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/3.2/org/bson/BSONObject.html#keySet--) method. That field is a `Set<String>`, with the description

> The names of the fields in this object

Thus, you might be able to use

```
for (String key: cursor.next().keySet()) {
    // do whatever with the key name here, f.ex.
    System.out.println(key);
}
```