# How to get keys from mongodb collection

Tags: mongodb

In my collection(collection name is "node"). And this collection contains following documents :

```
{
  "GEOLOCATION": {
    "GEO_CODE": [],
    "ACTIVE_GEOLOCATION": false
  },
  "META": {
    "CATEGORY": "levis",
    "DESCRIPTION": "dsad",
    "PRIVACY": "PUBLIC",
    "TEMPLATE_NAME": "A",
    "TEMPLATE_GROUP": "Product",
    "KEYWORDS": ["sda"],
    "CREATEDBY": "",
    "SUBCATEGORY": "Blue",
    "PRODUCT_TEMPLATE_TYPE": "Consumable",
    "UOM": "",
    "TEMPLATE_SUBGROUP": ""
  },
  "VARIENTS": [{
    "COMMENT": "Demo",
    "INDEX": 0,
    "NAME": "Price",
    "IS_PARENT": false,
    "DATATYPE": "Text",
    "ACCESS": "PUBLIC",
    "PARENT_VARIENT": "Parem",
    "TYPE": "PERMANENT"
  }]
}
```

I want do a query so that I can fetch keys form `geolocation, Meta`.

For example in my query I want to pass `Meta` and want to fetch only keys likes :

`CATEGORY,DESCRIPTION, PRIVACY,TEMPLATE_NAME,TEMPLATE_GROUP`.

For achieving this I run following query :

```
Object.keys(db.nodes.findOne())
```

But it shows following result :

```
[ "_id", "GEOLOCATION", "META", "VARIENTS" ]
```

Above result not expected result I want some thing like this,

expected output :

```
[CATEGORY,DESCRIPTION, PRIVACY,TEMPLATE_NAME,TEMPLATE_GROUP] // META object values.
```

Comment: brother i m agree with u. But i am getting problem, thats the reason i post it.

Comment: I understand you, and I also ask a lot of questions here when I have problems. Just try to show people what have you done and what problem are you facing.

Comment: You can only get the direct keys but not sub document keys.

Answer (score 0):

Check out **variety.js**
https://github.com/variety/variety

An open source project created by the output of this question on StackOverflow
https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366065/131809