# How to retrieve a value from mongoDB?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-java, mongo-java-driver

I am new to mongoDB and using java with mongoDB. I have a json where I want to retrieve the column names and not the value.I also need to store it in two different array.

Desired output is:

> column [ ] =  views, AddToCart, AddToWishList, ZoomedProductImage
>
> list  [ ] = fSymbol, num, operator

and the JSON:

```
{
    "views": {
        "fSymbol": "",
        "num": 0.1,
        "operator": "*"
    },
    "AddToCart": {
        "fSymbol": "+",
        "num": 0.15,
        "operator": "*"
   },
   "AddToWishList": {
       "fSymbol": "+", 
       "num": 0.1,
       "operator": "*"
   },
   "ZoomedProductImage": {
       "fSymbol": "+",
       "num": 0.07,
       "operator": "*"
   }   
}
```

Comment: Please visit this link hope this will help you .

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection

Comment: @praveen_programmer thanks man..but i need to do it through java.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `keySet()` method.

```
BasicDBObject searchQuery = new BasicDBObject();
DBCursor cursor = table.find(searchQuery);

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
    System.out.println(cursor.next().keySet());
}
```

check the [docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/org/bson/BSONObject.html#keySet())

Comment: Also,I need to store it in a string array.

Comment: Gives this error:  

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap$KeySet cannot be cast to com.mongodb.BasicDBObject

Comment: **while (cursor2.hasNext()) {
   
  
   BasicDBObject a=(BasicDBObject)cursor2.next().keySet();
  
  }**

Comment: ok my bad try `Set<String> a=cursor.next().keySet();` method `keySet()` return `Set<String>`

Answer (score 1):

Since [BasicDBObject](http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.13/com/mongodb/BasicDBObject.html) extends HashMap, you have just to get the keyset from it.