# how to read all fields and their type of a mongo db collection using java?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java

how to read all fields and their type  of a mongo db collection using java?
collection is as following. Each document may not have all fields

```
{ "_id" : { "oid" : "5117fa92f1d3a4093d0d3903"} },
{ "_id" : { "oid" : "5117fa93f1d3a4093d0d3904"} , "ip" : "127.0.0.1" },
{ "_id" : { "oid" : "5117fa93f1d3a4093d0d3904"} , "ip" : "127.0.0.1" ,"price" : 2000}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection)

Comment: And the link you are looking for in there is this: https://github.com/variety/variety . Implement in Java if you really must.