# How to investigate file structure in mongodb?

Tags: json, mongodb, discovery

Being a newbie to mongodb, my apologies if this is a trivial question, hopefully not.

I've got a set of 10 json files generated on a mongodb db, for which I would like to investigate the structure (fields, names, sizes, etc.). I know how to import json files into a db/collection on my mongo system and then use dbfind. However this works for specific fields which you need to know in advance, right?

In a relational SQL DB I would simply import the files and then go through the field names, sizes, even export it to a standard file format (.CSV, etc).

- When you know nothing about your source files, what is the equivalent
  strategy for MongoDB?
- Is there a command that lists all the fields/elements in the doc?
- Can you export the DB/collection from mongo, to a different format
  that is more manageable for discovery (e.g. .csv, or a SQL database).

Thanks in advance,           p

Answer (score 1):

In order to list all the fields in a mongo collection use variety https://github.com/variety/variety

OR

```
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "my_collection",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "my_collection" + "_keys"
})
```

Then run distinct on the resulting collection so as to find all the keys:

```
db[mr.result].distinct("_id")
["foo", "bar", "baz", "_id", ...]
```

[MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection)

FOR MONGO EXPORT

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/

For mongo export in csv format, you have to mention the fields you want to export, which you can get from above.

```
mongoexport --db users --collection contacts --type=csv --fields name,address --out /opt/backups/contacts.csv
```

Comment: Tried, then had to stop. I had some problems probably 'cause of my inexperience. This is what I do: 
1I import the json file using cmd into test db, collection example  -OK
2) I go to mongo shell. Run your mapreduce approach. I get error {"ok":0, "errmsg": "ns does not exist"}

I haven't tried variety or export yet.

Comment: Just yours:
mr = db.runCommand({
  "mapreduce" : "example",
  "map" : function() {
    for (var key in this) { emit(key, null); }
  },
  "reduce" : function(key, stuff) { return null; }, 
  "out": "example" + "_keys"
})   ,      of course not sure of meaning or the like.

Comment: dude, it means, ns doesn't exist means that you're accessing a non-existent database or collection. Check their names