# mongoose: return only keys from a document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document as follows:

```
var data={"john:"friend",
          "fruit":"banana",
           "tv":[{"livingroom":"led",
                   "bedroom":"lcd"
                   "fruit":"banana"}]}
```

and I am trying to return an array of all its unique keys as follows:

```
["john","fruit,livingroom,bedroom]
```

so I have the following code:

```
var mykeys=[];
database.find({},function(result){
    result.forEach(function(each){
         for (key in each){
             mykeys.push(key)
         };
    }});
```

But this returns a whole bunch of objects I don't need like:

```
[$__, isNew, errors, _doc, $__original_save, save, _pres, _posts....]
```

Is there anyway I can get rid of these keys which aren't in the document?
I am aware of this `mapreduce` answer here [MongoDB get the names of all the keys in a MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection) but I do not know how to translate it into mongoose. AFAIK mongoose doesn't support runCommand.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection)

Comment: @Bertrand Martel:I did look at that the solution but it seems too complicated for what I want. I don't need to find unique keys in a collection, just all keys in a document without the vituals. Also I'm not too sure how to implement mapreduce in mongoose.

Comment: Do you mean you want to extract keys from one document (any document) from your collection ?

Comment: @Bertrand Martel: Actually you're right I am kind of looking for the same thing! But I still don't know how to translate the answer into mongoose.

Answer (score 8):

You have to use the `_doc` property as this contains your actual document. In addition, you can just use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to get a list of properties.

```
var mykeys;
database.findOne({}, function(result) {
    mykeys = Object.keys(result._doc);
});
```

Comment: This answer works, but I just realised that I have subarrays in my document, which seems to be messing this up :-(. So I have upvoted your answer anyway and edited by question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you may still need it, but i manged to get it done in Nestjs and Mongoose using this code:

```
    async leadModel(): Promise<any> {
    const keys = this.leadsModel.findOne();
    return Object.keys(keys.schema.obj)
}
```

It's still not the best version of it and also throws me a warning that the property doesnt exist on my type, but it works perfectly. Returns only keys of the collection. If you remove `Object.keys()` it will also return nested keys.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @str answer, don't forget to add error as first callback argument

```
  let tableKeys 
  TRow.findOne({}, (err, result) {
    tableKeys = Object.keys(result._doc);
  });
```

You might also want to delete '_id' and '__v' from your keys object