# How to get index name from object with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have some objects in Mongodb created according to this mongoose Schema

```
const MetalSchema = mongoose.Schema({
dia_6:{type:Number},
dia_8:{type:Number},
dia_10:{type:Number},
dia_12:{type:Number},
dia_15:{type:Number}
});
```

All Objects have different quantity of key:value pairs. How to get the **key names** which are present in Object in DB?

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use something like this

```
   MetalSchema.schema.eachPath(function(path) {
   console.log(path);
   });
```

Comment: Yes it got all key names with `MetalSchema.schema.eachPath`, but from Schema, I want to get key names from real Object in db not from Schema

Answer (score 0):

I got index names with this code:

```
var mykeys;
database.findOne({}, function(result) {
    mykeys = Object.keys(result._doc);
});
```

Great thank's for STR for his answer in [neighber question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38684419/mongoose-return-only-keys-from-a-document?rq=1)