# How can I delete all fields from document except a some list? (mongoDB)

Tags: mongodb

Good day to all. I want to delete all fields from document except a some list. I know about $unset operator, but I don't know how can I use it in my task. Thank you in advance.

Comment: There is an answer here about listing all unique keys in a collection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection then you could you could remove all keys you don't want to remove from that list.  then loop through and unset the unneeded keys in each document.

Comment: I thought mongo has some operator(as $unset), which remove this fields by one request without loop. But I think this will help me. Thank you =)

Answer (score 0):

```
db.products.update(
   { sku: "unknown" },
   { $unset: { quantity: "", instock: "" } }
)
```

The above query will delete  quantity and instock fields from all the product documents where sku is unknown.

> you can write your query on the lines of the above example, **however if
>   you simply want to remove few fields from every document just ignore
>   the condition section i.e. sku :"unknown" instead pass {} and it will
>   affect every document in your collection.**

Comment: Thank you, but I want to delete all fields except some list. I have only the list of fields which I want keep, and all other fields i want to delete.

Comment: so you mean its the other way around. ok i wll try to figure out a query that helps you.