# MongoDB - query on property names

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB collection with several documents (not all of them) of the form:

```
{
    "name" : "...",
    "title" : "...",
    "5411b4a0e4b0bdc638535116" : "..."
}
```

i.e. with an unwanted property (probably set by accident) basically having an `ObjectId` as name.

I'm wondering if there's a way to query all those documents. 
I was thinking on some kind of regex (e.g. if property name's first char is a digit), but I'm not sure this is possible at all as I couldn't find anything on this matter.

I'm using MongoDB 3.2.

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection