# Removing fields from Mongodb based on the field name

Tags: mongodb, field

I have a collection containing demographic data by zip code. It has 6 columns for every age group:

- `Total; Estimate; AGE # - #`
- `Total; Margin of Error; AGE # - #`
- `Male; Estimate; AGE # - #`
- `Male; Margin of Error; AGE # - #`
- `Female; Estimate; AGE # - #`
- `Female; Margin of Error; AGE # - #`

There are around 10 age groups, so there are 60 fields. And there are over 33,000 documents (33,000+ zipcodes). So there's a lot of data. Is there a way to remove all the margin of error columns using some sort of SQL-like "like"? Like remove any field "%Margin%".

Comment: Can you show a sample document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can get list of all fields as described in [MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection), conditionally emit fields that match your criteria, and iterate the result to `$unset` each matched field.

Answer (score 0):

So I did `doc = db.AgeSex.findOne();` to get all the columns.

And then I did:

```
for(key in doc){
    if(key.includes("Margin")){
        db.AgeSex.update({},{$unset:{ (""+key):""}});
    }
};
```

and I get `SyntaxError: invalid property id`