# Getting a list of unique fields within a collection including nested

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I've been searching the MongoDB docs and also looking at javascript alternatives. However, it does not seem like theres an easy way to do this.

I need to get a list of the unique field names within my collection. Some of the documents contain more fields than others.

Comment: Please show some example of your input data, what would you like to achieve and what have you done so far

Comment: I believe you may be looking for this: [MongoDB Get names of all keys in collection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10366065/1073358)