# Query using mongoexport for req.user.id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, database-backups, mongoexport

I am trying to export a database called `asset-management` and all collections where `req.user.id` except the `users` collection. I can't seem to get the below to work.

`mongoexport --db asset-management --collection * --type=csv --query  '{"author.id": req.user.id}' --out userbackup.csv`

I get this error message:

**Error parsing command line: unknown option type**

Comment: What version of MongoDB are you using? The `--type` flag was added in v3 so this message "unknown option type" implies you are using a version < 3.0. If so, then the pre 3.0 equivalent of `--type=csv` is: `--csv`.

Comment: @glytching I am running V2.6 so I changed the one thing you mentioned and I got the error `Error parsing command line: too many positional options`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mongo 2.6, this should work:

```
mongoexport --db asset-management --csv --query  "{'author.id': 'req.user.id'}" --fields \"fieldNameA,fieldNameB\" --out userbackup.csv
```

The differences between this and the `mongoexport` command in your question are:

1. Swapped `"` and `'` in the `--query` parameter, to address "Error parsing command line: too many positional options"
2. Removed `--collection *` this looks like like it is intended to mean *all collection* in which case it is redundant since that's the default behaviour. In your question you stated: "I am trying to export a database called asset-management and all collections where req.user.id except the users collection", this is not possible when using `mongoexport` ... you can export a specific collection or all collections but you cannot blacklist a single collection
3. Added `--fields` because according [to the docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/v2.6/reference/program/mongoexport/#cmdoption-mongoexport-csv) ...

   > If you specify --csv, then you must also use either the --fields or the --fieldFile option to declare the fields to export from the collection.

Comment: Thanks is it possible to include all fields quickly instead of me putting in every field manually?

Comment: If you can accept JSON output then remove `--csv` and you won't need `--fields`. But if you **must** have csv output then you are forced to tell MongoDB _which_ fields you are interested in because MongoDB is schema-less whereas CSV has a fixed columnar layout so MongoDB needs to be told something about your desired CSV format. I'm not aware of a shortcut meaning _all fields_. You'd likely have to run something to [gather all field names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/mongodb-get-names-of-all-keys-in-collection) and then update your mongoexport command.