# pymongo aggregate collection keys

Tags: pymongo-3.x, flask-pymongo

Using this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570730/7626649

I'd like to do this with flask-pymongo.

Specifically I'd like to perform the below query in flask-pymongo and/or pymongo (It seems like if it can be done in one then it could be done in the other..I hope):

```
db.things.aggregate([
  {"$project":{"arrayofkeyvalue":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}},
  {"$unwind":"$arrayofkeyvalue"},
  {"$group":{"_id":null,"allkeys":{"$addToSet":"$arrayofkeyvalue.k"}}}
])
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
@app.route('/reports/<site>/<system>/<data_type>', methods=['GET'])
def get_keys_for_collection(site, system, data_type):
    pipeline = [
        {"$project":{"arrayofkeyvalue":{"$objectToArray":"$$ROOT"}}},   
        {"$unwind":"$arrayofkeyvalue"},
        {"$group":{"_id": None,"allkeys":{"$addToSet":"$arrayofkeyvalue.k"}}}   
    ]
    db, options = get_db_handle(site)
    collection = "%s_%s" % (system, data_type)
    pp.pprint(db.command('aggregate', collection, pipeline=pipeline, explain=True))
    return jsonify({'results': list(db.collection.aggregate(pipeline))})
```

I have verified that 'db' is an active Flask-Pymongo connection to the database that contains the collection being queried.  Here is the output of db.command() with explain=True:

```
{   'ok': 1.0,
'stages': [   {   '$cursor': {   'query': {},
                                 'queryPlanner': {   'indexFilterSet': False,
                                                     'namespace': 'MYDB.collection',
                                                     'parsedQuery': {},
                                                     'plannerVersion': 1,
                                                     'rejectedPlans': [],
                                                     'winningPlan': {   'direction': 'forward',
                                                                        'stage': 'COLLSCAN'}}}},
              {   '$project': {   '_id': True,
                                  'arrayofkeyvalue': {   '$objectToArray': [   '$$ROOT']}}},
              {'$unwind': {'path': '$arrayofkeyvalue'}},
              {   '$group': {   '_id': {'$const': None},
                                'allkeys': {   '$addToSet': '$arrayofkeyvalue.k'}}}]}
```

I omitted the actual database and collection name, and replaced them with MYDB.collection above.  The db.command() proves that db.connection is a valid connection and the problem doesn't lie with syntax on that part of the query.

I get an empty list as the result with no errors. The URL was modified to not reveal certain information.  See db.command() results for proof that the db connection and collection exist and are being connected to properly.

```
curl http://0.0.0.0:5000/reports/site/system/data_type
{
   "results": []
}
```

What I'm using:

```
Python 3.6.5
MongoDB shell version v3.6.5
PyMongo v3.4.0
Flask-Pymongo v0.5.2
```

Comment: Do `MYDB.db.collection` and `db.things` refer to the same database and collection in both these examples? In particular, it looks like probably the collection name is different, assuming that these are exact copy/paste.

Comment: Nice catch! I made the correction.  The collection I'm running this on does exist, but it does not solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: What version of pymongo, mongodb, and flask-pymongo are you using? The `aggregate` method should be a pass-through, so if you can get it to work with pymongo natively, it should work with flask-pymongo, too

Comment: Can you update your question with the exact code you're using? I'm unable to reproduce this with what you have shared so far, so there may be some more subtle issue in the surrounding code or usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax issue with the aggregate command:

```
db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

should be

```
db[collection].aggregate(pipeline)
```