# List available fields in a MongoDB database

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql, nosql-aggregation

MongoDB is a Schemaless, NoSQL database.

But for simplicity and ease of use, users will use some form of schema to have some understanding of their data and simplify their use of database.

Is/are there any methods with which one can list available fields in a MongoDB database?

A work around I use is to use db.collection.findOne() or list first few documents, but I don't think it's a reliable method.

Comment: Flagged, possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/get-names-of-all-keys-in-the-collection

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get names of all keys in the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298870/get-names-of-all-keys-in-the-collection)