# MongoDB: How to reorder document Fields that got jumbled in the past

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

My DB has many documents with mostly random field order as displayed in Mongo Compass. The first field is always _id but the rest of the fields could be in any order. This makes scanning records by eye very difficult.
I have read that this reordering due to upserts no longer happens with Mongo 4.2  and I have upgraded  - but the problem remains.
Is there a way for me to reorder my fields so each document in a collection has the same field order - say -id first then a-z?

Comment: You can try reading each document in a language that preserves hash key order, reordering fields as you see fit, then writing each document back.

Comment: Yes but it would be a lot of work! I may investigate some migration/export methods to see if they restore to 'normal' field order.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "normal" field order. Since bson implements maps as lists of ordered key-value pairs, I would expect all regular tools to preserve the order of keys that currently exists for each individual document.

Comment: So just order of key addition for each particular document?  A schema 'sort' utility would be nice....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $replaceWith to do this.
https://mongoplayground.net/p/VBzpabZuJpy

```
db.YOURCOLLECTION.updateMany({}, [
  {$replaceWith: {
    $mergeObjects: [
      {
        "fieldA": "$fieldA",
        "fieldB": "$fieldB",
        "fieldC": "$fieldC",
        "fieldD": "$fieldD",
        "fieldE": "$fieldE"
      },
      "$$ROOT"
    ]
  }}
])
```

Comment: thanks, your solution does indeed work!  But it requires explicit naming of all the input fields or they are lost. So if I have 100 records and only one of them has  a 'specialfield' then I need to add specialfield to the aggregate function or it will be lost. Is there a catchall specification to deal with this? - equivalent of    anyfield : anyfield. Or a way to output all of the distinct top level fields  of a collection so I can be sure I caught them all?

Comment: Yes, I just posted a edit. From https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/#replaceroot-with-a-new-document-created-from-root-and-a-default-document

Comment: If you still want to get all your field names anyway, take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/43570730/13885615

Comment: Thanks, the $$ROOT solved the missing field issue but in testing with your neat simulator I found out that the fields were being sorted alphabetically no matter what order was specified - so if you move fieldA to the bottom of the list it still merges first. which is fine! So, I deleted the whole specification and ran it again with just $$ROOT and it works!  - ie. $mergeObjects: [ {}, "$ROOT" ]

Comment: Your solution helped me a lot. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can try reading each document in a language that preserves hash key order, reordering fields as you see fit, then writing each document back.

Since bson implements maps as lists of ordered key-value pairs, I expect all regular tools to preserve the order of keys that currently exists for each individual document.