# MongoDB group all keys and values in a collection by a certain field

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have collection like this:

```
id:..
Category:Car
Type:BMW

id:..
Category:Car
Type:Ferrari
Color:Red

id..
Category:Bikes
Type:Mountain Bike

id..
Category:Bikes
Type:BMX
```

I want to make an aggregate and a grouping to have a result like this:

```
[{Category:Car Type:[BMW,Ferrari] Color:[Red]},
{Category:Bikes Type:[Mountain Bike,BMX]}]
```

So basically the main field is our Category, and every document keys which is part of that category are sorted out and their values grouped.

Is it possible to achieve this with aggregate?

I tried to make it with $objectToArray but it's not even close to what I want:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $project: {
      data: {
        $objectToArray: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      data: "$data.k",
      value: "$data.v"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$data",
    
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$value",
    
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: null,
      
      keys: {
        $addToSet: "$data"
      },
      values: {
        $addToSet: "$value"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track there.

When converting the entire object to an array, also save the Category field.

The stages needed:

- $project to save the Category and convert the object to an array
- $unwind the array to consider each field separately
- $match to remove `_id`, `Category` and any other fields you don't want grouped from the array
- $group by `Category` and `k` to push the values of each key into an array
- $group by `Category` to collect the keys and arrays together
- $project to convert the array with collected values to an object
- $addFields to inject the Category into the new object
- $replaceRoot to promote the new object

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$project: {
      Category: 1,
      fields: {$objectToArray: "$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$unwind: "$fields"},
  {$match: {"fields.k": {$not: {$in: ["_id","Category"]}} }},
  {$group: {
      _id: {
        Category: "$Category",
        key: "$fields.k"
      },
      value: {$push: "$fields.v"}
  }},
  {$group: {
      _id: "$_id.Category",
      fields: {
        $push: {
          "k": "$_id.key",
          "v": "$value"
        }
      }
  }},
  {$project: {
      fields: {$arrayToObject: "$fields"}
  }},
  {$addFields: {
      "fields.Category": "$_id"
  }},
  {$replaceRoot: { newRoot: "$fields"}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/A2YfhoE6S80)

Comment: Just a quick question, how can i transform it to an array. Because when I use .toArray often happens that Type is followed by Color and when I refresh the page the Color is the first and the Type is the last element and I would need to have the same order. Thank you very much again for your answer.

Comment: Hello @Joe. This is a little off, but I came up with a similar interesting and hard (maybe just for me) question. Maybe if you have time, and you would like to, you can check it out, because I am curious about your opinion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67446827/mongodb-js-advanced-faceted-search-how-to-get-only-relevant-categories-value